Google Sheets Formula to obtain the last value in a column whose date is the max between a date range
In my Summary worksheet, I want cell A1 to display the last value from my Final Tracker worksheet in a column J whose date in column B is the last row between a date range identified in Summary G8 and G9.
Sample data (Dates are in dd-mm-yyyy format):
Cell Summary!G8 = 01-04-2024
Cell Summary!G9 = 30-04-2024

Final Tracker Worksheet (Data starts at B6):



Row
Date (Column B)
Value (Column J)




6
01-04-2024
$42.73


7
02-04-2024
$106.28


8
02-04-2024
$74.42


9
05-04-2024
$6.25


10
05-04-2024
$40.38


11
05-04-2024
$75.13


12
01-05-2024
$13.56



The result should be $75.13
The total number of rows will grow over time so the range cannot be hardcoded.
I've tried an approach using this formula but it returns a value that doesn't even exist in my data set:
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(('Final Tracker'!B:B >= G8) * ('Final Tracker'!B:B <= G9)) = 0, "", 
  INDEX('Final Tracker'!J:J, SUMPRODUCT(('Final Tracker'!B:B >= G8) * ('Final Tracker'!B:B <= G9)) * ROW('Final Tracker'!B:B)) / SUMPRODUCT(('Final Tracker'!B:B >= G8) * ('Final Tracker'!B:B <= G9)))



You may try:
=chooserows(filter('Final Tracker'!J6:J,isbetween('Final Tracker'!B6:B,G8,G9)),-1)


Adjust the ranges accordingly if they aren't...

